# (Corona SDK) How cancel math.random?

Tags: math, random, sdk, coronasdk

Here i have some code:

```
function CountDown()
             if(time_remaining > 1)then
                 time_remaining = time_remaining - 1;
                 print ("Loading menu")  
                  local function main( event )

                    -- LAUNCH A ROCKET 
                    if math.ceil(math.random() * 200) == 10 and launch == false then
                        Particles.GetEmitter  ("Launcher1").rotation = -35
                        Particles.GetEmitter  ("Launcher2").rotation = 20
                        Particles.StartEmitter("Launcher1", true)
                        Particles.StartEmitter("Launcher2", true)

                    end

                    -- UPDATE PARTICLES
                    Particles.Update()

                end

                -- timer.performWithDelay( 33, main, 1 )
                Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", main )
             else
                 time_remaining = 0
                 print ("Load Go!")
                 menuLoad = transition.to( menuLoad, { time=575, y=-500 })
             end

        end

        count_timer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, CountDown, time_total);
```

When i switch my scene, i cancel all emitters by Particles.CleanUp(), but i cant cancel math.random, it tries to start my emitters anyway, but because they are nils already(Particles.CleanUp), so it gives me an error

```
Runtime error
    ...me development/Skipjack Rollout Design2/mainmenu.lua:560: attempt to index a nil value
stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    ...me development/Skipjack Rollout Design2/mainmenu.lua:560: in function <...me development/Skipjack Rollout Design2/mainmenu.lua:556>
    ?: in function <?:226>
```

help me please! How an i cancel math.random?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking here but it seems like you've got several problems.

1. you've lost the handle to the main function that you've added as a frame listener
2. you're adding it repeatedly each time you detect that time_remaining > 1, meaning that it's running multiple times per frame
3. you're replacing your reference to menuLoad with a timer handle (although this might be intentional.

I'm inferring from the code that you want your particles to play for time_total seconds at which point you'll transition to menuLoad?  If so, what about the following:

```
local function main(event)
    -- LAUNCH A ROCKET
    if math.ceil(math.random() * 200) == 10 and launch == false then
        Particles.GetEmitter  ("Launcher1").rotation = -35
        Particles.GetEmitter  ("Launcher2").rotation = 20
        Particles.StartEmitter("Launcher1", true)
        Particles.StartEmitter("Launcher2", true)
    end

    -- UPDATE PARTICLES
    Particles.Update()
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", main)
timer.performWithDelay(time_total * 1000, function() 
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", main)
    transition.to( menuLoad, { time=575, y=-500 })
end)
```